# React Router V4 - Components not rendering under <Switch>

Tags: react-redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to turn a block of hardcoded `<Route />`s into something that's dynamically generated from a config variable. Eg.

From

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/documents" component={Documents} exact />
        <Route path="/documents/faq" component={DocFAQ} />
        <Route path="/documents/translations" component={Translations} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

To

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Home,
        exact: true
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        component: About
    },
    {
        path: '/documents',
        component: Documents,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/faq',
                component: DocFAQ
            },
            {
                path: '/translations',
                component: Translations
            }
        ]
    }
];

const RecursiveRoute = ({ route, parentPath = '' }) => {
    const path = parentPath + route.path;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Route path={path} exact={route.exact || (route.children != null)} component={route.component} />
            {route.children && route.children.map((childRoute, i) => <RecursiveRoute key={i} route={childRoute} parentPath={path} />)}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            {routes.map((route, i) => <RecursiveRoute key={i} route={route} />)}
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);
```

This code generates exactly what I want when I take the mapping call outside of `<Router>`; eg. I can verify that it outputs the exact same code as the hardcoded block from before. When it's inside the `<Switch>` however, only the first route in the `routes` array is getting mapped--nothing else is generated. Putting logging statements inside `<RecursiveRoute>` confirms this.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Another weird thing is that if I paste `<RecursiveRoute>`'s JSX right into the `map` statement, it works (except I can't make it recursive in this case):

```
<Switch>
    {routes.map((route, i) => <Route key={i} path={route.path} exact={route.exact || (route.children != null)} component={route.component} />)}
</Switch>
```

But if I keep it outsourced to another component, the mapping fails again.

---

**[Edit] Solution:**

Based on [mehamasum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715197/1014005), changing `<RecursiveRoute>` from a component to a function solved this problem:

```
function generateRecursiveRoute(route, parentPath = '') {
    const path = parentPath + route.path;
    const routeHasChildren = (route.children != null);
    const baseHtml = <Route path={path} exact={route.exact || routeHasChildren} component={route.component} key={path} />;
    return !routeHasChildren ?
        baseHtml :
        <React.Fragment key={path}>
            {baseHtml}
            {route.children.map((childRoute) => generateRecursiveRoute(childRoute, path))}
        </React.Fragment>;
}

const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            {routes.map((route) => generateRecursiveRoute(route))}
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by the 'mapping fails'? Some kind of error thrown?

Comment: As in "only the first route in the routes array is getting mapped--nothing else is generated". So in this example, only the Home route is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` is [implemented in such a way](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Switch.js) that you provide multiple Components as children and it will render the first Component's `component` with matching `path`. So if you provide something other than a Route as child (something that doesn't have those `path` and `component` props) you need to make sure you write your rendering logic in there. Because `Switch` doesn't know what to do here, as it sees no `component` or `render` prop associated with that child.

So when you were mapping to `Route`s directly they were working, but when you were mapping to `RecursiveRoute` it was failing. It had no `path` nor `component` on it, right?

I have updated your code a little bit so that the routes are directly rendered as children of `Switch`:

```
// refactor of RecursiveRoute to
// use it as an utility function, not as component

const getRecursiveRoute = route => {
  if (route.children) {
    const RootComponent = route.component;
    return (
      <Route
        key={route.path}
        path={route.path}
        render={props => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment>
              {/* render the root matching component*/}
              <RootComponent {...props} />

              {/* render the subroutes */}
              {/* TODO: consider having a Switch here too */}

              {route.children.map(route =>
                getRecursiveRoute({
                  ...route,
                  path: props.match.url + route.path
                })
              )}
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
  return (
    <Route
      key={route.path}
      path={route.path}
      exact={route.exact || route.children != null}
      component={route.component}
    />
  );
};

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>{routes.map(route => getRecursiveRoute(route))}</Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit x2kx286x44]

You might have to fix some edge cases about exact routing. Hope it helps.

Comment: This makes sense now, thanks! I found that simply changing `<RecursiveRoute>` into a function (eg. without using render) worked just fine as well.